# Select Radio Button / input value in Open box on website using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to punch the radio button question and want to input the value in an open text box as well (using VBA). Below is the script I am using.

I tried multiple things, looked at other websites as well but it is not working.

It would be great if someone can guide me.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim Region, VOCSentDate As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Region = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
VOCSentDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "website link....."
Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
```

I'm not sure how to punch the radio button question. I tried the 3 types for Open textbox below but none of them are not working, throwing object required error

```
IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_body_7F22FA6E-5D77-426A-AA84-68D833FA05C1_3").Value = VOCSentDate

IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_body_7F22FA6E-5D77-426A-AA84-68D833FA05C1_3").innerText = VOCSentDate

IE.Document.all("ctl00_body_7F22FA6E-5D77-426A-AA84-68D833FA05C1_3").Value = VOCSentDate

Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

-------------- HTML of the Radio button --------------

```
<div class="SurveyItem  RadioButtonList Item1">
  <div class="ItemText">
    <span class="NoItemNumber"></span><span class="QuestionText">Please select your region:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Validators">
    <span id="ctl00_body_ctl12" style="color:Red;display:none;">A response to this question is required</span>
  </div>
  <div id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" class="Response">
    <div class="ResponseOption">
      <input id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$ctl00_body_ctl00_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" value="01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_1" /><label for="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_1">Americas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ResponseOption AlternatingRow">
      <input id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$ctl00_body_ctl00_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" value="01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_2" /><label for="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_2">ANZ</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ResponseOption">
      <input id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$ctl00_body_ctl00_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" value="01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_3" /><label for="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_3">APAC</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ResponseOption AlternatingRow">
      <input id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_4" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$ctl00_body_ctl00_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" value="01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_4" /><label for="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_4">APME</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ResponseOption">
      <input id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_5" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$ctl00_body_ctl00_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" value="01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_5" /><label for="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_5">Europe</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ResponseOption AlternatingRow">
      <input id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_6" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$ctl00_body_ctl00_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" value="01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_6" /><label for="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_6">India</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ResponseOption">
      <input id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_7" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$ctl00_body_ctl00_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1" value="01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_7" /><label for="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_7">North America</label>
    </div>
```

------------------- HTML of Open End -------------------------

```
<div class="SurveyItem  Item3">
  <div class="ItemText">
    <span class="NoItemNumber"></span><span class="QuestionText">EOPR First Sent Date (dd/mm/yyyy)</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Validators">
    <span id="ctl00_body_ctl52" style="color:Red;display:none;">A response to this question is required</span><span id="ctl00_body_ctl53" style="color:Red;display:none;">Incorrect Date Format</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Response">
    <input name="ctl00$body$01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_3" type="text" id="ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_3" class="TextBox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By punch do you mean check or select? Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr;**

The following are based on the HTML as shown. If there are parent `form/frame/iframe` tags involved they will also need to be negotiated before making the selections below.

---

**Radio buttons:**

For the radio buttons you can use a CSS selector combination to target the page styling and return a nodeList of all of the radio button elements. You can then select by index the appropriate button

```
Dim aNodeList As Object
Set aNodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".ResponseOption [type=radio]")
aNodeList.item(0).Click '<==Select first  option
```

I think click may be likely method here as I can't see a checked attribute, else the syntax would be  `aNodeList.item(0).checked = True`

The returned nodeList is as follows by index

[image]

---

**Textbox:**

There is an ID for the input box so you can use an ID selector, #, to target

```
ie.document.querySelector("#ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_3").Value = "myText"
```

Answer (score 0):

To choose a radio button style input, make the checked property true.

```
IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_1_6").checked = true
```

An input textbox gets its value set.

```
IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_body_01EE9560-B1F9-4BA3-A922-9D53A1120FC2_3").value = format(VOCSentDate, "d/m/yy")
```